# Office 365 API ews calendar rest api - Attendees null

Tags: api, office365

I'm using the rest services with the new Office 365 API Preview.

My problem occurs when i'm querying to get the events of a user (aka for example : **https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Calendar/Events**) , when i'm doing this i manage to retrieve some datas as the event list including start date, end date, subject, location but i'm not able to retrieve the attendees list of the event. The list is always empty (aka "Attendees":[],) even if i can see some other peoples on this event through the GUI (online or via the client). Just for information, i'm the owner of the 0365 tenant.

Is there any way to retrieve the attendees list? Is it a right issue or is it due to the preview character of the api?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can indeed reproduce what you say.

Not even calling the REST service directly can I get any attendees to show up. With or without expand.

Just realized, that if you ask for a specific calendar event, then you do get the attendees list. Don't know why it's not odata compliant and can be expanded to be included in the event result set.

Here's an example of what you get if you call https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=')

```
{"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/$metadata#Users('admin%40sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events/$entity","@odata.id":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=')","@odata.etag":"W/\"3K+KB/hX3k6C9PlNLkSHqgAAE4eIQw==\"","@odata.editLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=')","Id":"AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=","ChangeKey":"3K+KB/hX3k6C9PlNLkSHqgAAE4eIQw==","Subject":"Meeting","BodyPreview":"","Body":{"ContentType":"HTML","Content":"<html>\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<style type=\"text/css\" style=\"display:none\"><!-- p { margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; }--></style>\r\n</head>\r\n<body dir=\"ltr\">\r\n<div id=\"OWAFontStyleDivID\" style=\"font-size:12pt;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;\">\r\n<p><br>\r\n</p>\r\n</div>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n"},"Importance":"Normal","Categories":[],"HasAttachments":false,"Start":"2014-06-22T19:30:00Z","End":"2014-06-22T20:00:00Z","Location":{"DisplayName":""},"ShowAs":"Busy","IsAllDay":false,"IsCancelled":false,"IsOrganizer":true,"ResponseRequested":true,"Type":"SingleInstance","SeriesId":null,"Attendees":[{"Name":"mail@sjkp.dk","Address":"mail@sjkp.dk","Status":{"Response":"Accepted","Time":"2014-06-22T19:55:38Z"},"Type":"Required"}],"Recurrence":null,"Attachments@odata.navigationLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=')/Attachments","Calendar@odata.navigationLink":"https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('admin@sjkpdevs.onmicrosoft.com')/Events('AAMkADgxZDFhOTkwLTdhZTEtNGI0Yy05OWM4LTgxYjU2NGJjOTM5NQBGAAAAAAAZ8w1ex-72T6eE6TA1YJtABwDcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAAAAAEOAADcr4oH_FfeToL0_U0uRIeqAAATh3axAAA=')/Calendar"}
```

Comment: It's working like that, thanks for your answer and the sample !

Answer (score 0):

Currently in order to get the Attendees for an Event in the ODATA API, you need to do a GET on individual events that are returned from the Events entity set.